# Arquivo SVG em CSS não executa função Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Estou a usar um SVG como `background-image`, via css:

```
#element {
    background-image: url('triangle.svg');
}
```

Então dentro do arquvio SVG eu chamo uma função no `onload` pois preciso passar parametros de cores RGB para o SVG e mudar o *fill* do `polygon` consoante o que o cliente tiver escolhido:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="114px" height="66px" viewBox="0 0 114 66" xml:space="preserve" onload="setParams()">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <![CDATA[
            function setParams() {
                alert('funcao!');
            }
        ]]>
    </script>
    <polygon id="polygon" points="114,0 0,66 114,66"/>
</svg>
```

O problema é que esse `onload="setParams"` no SVG (que está como `backgounr-image`) não é interpretado na hora que renderizo a pagina que esta com o CSS. Ou seja, o meu "index" linka o CSS mas ele por sua vez não vai ate o SVG interpretar o JS.

Se eu acessar o SVG diretamente na url ai sim ele interpreta o JS e executa a função, mas através do index que chama o css não chega ate o javascript no svg.

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54602/discussion-on-question-by-guilherme-lessa-arquivo-svg-em-css-nao-executa-funcao)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aqui vão duas ideias:

## Usando `mask-image`

Se o que queres é usar a silhueta desse SVG podes usar o mask-image e mudar o background-color do container dessa imagem. Isso fica bem simples e o código é só este:

```
background-repeat: none;
background-color: #ccf; /* esta é a propriedade que vais querer mudar */
mask-image: url('triangle.svg');
-webkit-mask-image: url('triangle.svg');
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fnvyx6ev/

## Usando `url('data:...`

Podes passar xml diretamente como `data` para a propriedade do elemento. Podes fazer isso assim:

```
var generateSVG = function (cor) {
    var el = '<svg version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="114px" height="66px" viewBox="0 0 114 66" xml:space="preserve">' +    
                 '<polygon id="polygon" fill="' + cor + '" points="114,0 0,66 114,66"/>'+
             '</svg>';
    return "url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8," + el + "')"
}
```

e depois aplicar ao elemento:

```
var svg = generateSVG(corPretendida);
element.style.backgroundImage = svg;
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nnvey1th/

Answer (score 1):

Achei uma forma de passar o conteúdo do arquivo SVG diretamente no CSS, assim podendo alterar a cor sem depender de JS dentro do SVG. Já passo a cor direto na propriedade fill.

```
background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8, <!-- aqui vai o conteúdo XML do SVG -->');

background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><svg version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="114px" height="66px" viewBox="0 0 114 66" xml:space="preserve"><polygon fill="rgb(128,128,128)" points="114,0 0,66 114,66"/></svg>');
```

Comment: A tua resposta tem o mesmo conteúdo da resposta que dei, usando `url(data:`. Talvez fosse melhor deixar isso como comentário na minha resposta ou explicando porque esta resposta é diferente daquela que já havia. De qualquer maneira marca uma delas como aceite para a pergunta ficar resolvida. Até breve!